# wrap a div around text without line breaks

Tags: css, html, whitespace, line-breaks

I've got some divs in my site but they only behave correctly in IE (I've tried IE9), not on Firefox, Chrome or Safari. The thing is, the div is set up like a tooltip and it needs to automatically know the width it will need to wrap its contents. Maybe its easier if I show first the code and then ask the question:

CSS

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: .8em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    background: #eee;
    border: solid 1px #aaa;
    border-radius: 8px;
    pointer-events: none;
}

div img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <img src='img/tooltips/image.jpg'>
    <em>Name:</em> Lorem ipsum<br />
    <em>Adress:</em> Dolor sit amet<br />
    <em>Job:</em> bli blu bla bli blu bla
</div>
```

The images are 75x75px.

My problem is that when the text below the first line is longer than it, the line breaks causing it to get out of position and under the picture. What I want to do is that every line is just one line and the div embraces all the text. I've tried `white-space: nowrap;` and all the different values of `white-space` but although it makes the line to be continuous the div doesn't change its width to accomodate all the text. Any solutions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had success with such a solution: Wrap the `em`s with a `p`.

```
<div>
    <img src='img/tooltips/image.jpg'>
    <p>
    <em>Name:</em> Lorem ipsum<br />
    <em>Adress:</em> Dolor sit amet<br />
    <em>Job:</em> bli blu bla bli blu bla bli blu bla bli blu bla 
    </p>
</div>
```

Add this style:

```
p {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I found the easiest solution. Just write

```
 white-space: nowrap;
```

and make sure it is float: left; or float: right;

this is all the code you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below, It will help you...

**Fiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/177/

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <img src='img/tooltips/image.jpg'>
    <em>Name:</em> Lorem ipsum
    <em>Adress:</em> Dolor sit amet
    <em>Job:</em> bli blu bla bli blu bl asdfgsdgsdgsdgdsg
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    font-size: .8em;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    background: #eee;
    border: solid 1px #aaa;
    border-radius: 8px;
    pointer-events: none;
    white-space: pre-wrap;      /* CSS3 */   
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; /* Firefox */    
    white-space: -pre-wrap;     /* Opera <7 */   
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;   /* Opera 7 */    
    word-wrap: break-word;      /* IE */
}



div img {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

**Output :**

[image]